# Druid Kafka ingestion (imply-2.2.3): kafka error NoReplicaOnlineException

Tags: java, indexing, apache-kafka, druid, bigdata

I use [Druid Kafka Indexing](http://druid.io/docs/0.10.0/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html) service to load my own streams from Kafka.

I use [Load from Kafka tutorial](https://docs.imply.io/on-premise/tutorial-kafka-indexing-service) to implement it.

Kafka has all setting by default (just extracted from tgz).

When I start **imply-2.2.3** (Druid) with empty data (after **var** remove folder) all works properly.

But when I stop **Kafka 2.11-0.10.2.0** and start it again occurs error and Druid Kafka ingestion no more works until I stop Imply(Druid) and remove all data (i.e. remove **var** folder).

Sometimes Druid just does not ingest data from Kafka even no errors in Kafka.
When I remove **var** folder in Druid all is repared until next same error.

**Error:**

```
kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [__consumer_offsets,19] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
    at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:73) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:339) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:200) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:115) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:112) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:112) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:67) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:342) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:160) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:85) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:51) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:681) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:677) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:677) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:677) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:224) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:?]
```

The steps that I did:

**1. Start Imply:**

```
bin/supervise -c conf/supervise/quickstart.conf
```

**2. Start Kafka:**

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**3. Create topic:**

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic wikiticker
```

**4. Enable Druid Kafka ingestion:**

```
curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d @quickstart/wikiticker-kafka-supervisor.json http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor
```

**5. Post events** to the Kafka topic which were then ingested into Druid by the Kafka indexing service

In all **.properties** files (common.runtime.properties, broker, coordinator, historical, middlemanager, overlord) added property:

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-caffeine-cache", "druid-histogram", "druid-datasketches", "druid-kafka-indexing-service"]
```

which includes **"druid-kafka-indexing-service"** to provide ingesting service.

I believe that such problems shouldn't occur with [Druid Kafka Indexing](http://druid.io/docs/0.10.0/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html).

Is there ways how to figure out that issue?

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates broker with id 0 is down and because it is the only broker hosting that partition, you can't use that partition right now. You have to make sure broker 0 is up and serving.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a single node Kafka cluster and that the only broker node is down. That's not a very fault tolerant setup. You should have 3 Kafka brokers and setup all topics with replication factor of 3 so that the system will work even if one or two Kafka brokers are down. Single node clusters are typically only used for development.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding 3 Kafka brokers and setup all topics with replication factor of 3 for Kafka stability.

In Druid I fixed problem by increasing `druid.worker.capacity` in middleManager and decreasing `taskDuration` in `ioConfig` of supervisor spec.

Details in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544339/druid-kafka-indexing-service-indexing-tasks-settings).